# How can I calculate the SNR of a signal from its frequency spectrum?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, noise

I am pulling data from a spectrum analyzer and am trying to use the snr function from the signal processing toolbox to calculate the signal-to-noise ratio of the signal. The problem is that the value I am getting for the SNR makes no sense. I am calling the function like this:

```
snr(power, freqValues, rwb, 'power')
```

And the value of the snr I get is -28.0343 +13.6438i with rwb = 1.8e4;
The graph created by snr looks like this:
[image: SNR]
And for reference this is what the frequency spectrum I am capturing looks like:
(This is created from plot(freqValues, power))
[image: freq]
The frequency ranges from 0-2MHz and the major peak is at 902kHz @10.4dBm.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read the MATLAB documentation for `snr()`, I see the following. Your input `power` as `sxx` is formatted incorrectly.

> sxx — Power spectrum
>
> nonnegative real-valued row or column vector
>
> Power spectrum, specified as a **real-valued nonnegative** row or column vector.
>
> The power spectrum must be **expressed in linear units**, not decibels. Use db2pow to convert decibel values to power values.